# Appending dict value in for loop, Python

Tags: python, dictionary, append

I'm trying to create some code in Python which sends a request to Steam Market. It is meant to provide the average price per day for each item, but I'm stuck with a problem when appending values to a dict.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from datetime import datetime
from decouple import config
import SteamMarket


game_id = config("GAME_ID_1")
SteamMarket.set_cookies(config("STEAM_LOGIN_SECURE"))
SteamMarket.iniate_cookies()


all_items_names = [
"M4A1-S | Moss Quartz (Factory New)",
]

item_date = defaultdict(list)
for item in all_items_names:
    item = SteamMarket.get_price_history(game_id, item)
    if item:
        item_price_data = item["prices"]
        if not item_price_data:
            continue
        else:
            date = []
            prices = []
            quantity = []
            for day in item_price_data:
                date.append(datetime.strptime(day[0][0:11], "%b %d %Y"))
                prices.append(day[1])
                quantity.append(day[2])
            for day in range(len(item_price_data) - 1, 1, -1):
                index = 1
                item_date[f'{date[day]}'] = [prices[day]]
                while date[day] == date[day - index]:
# if the item is sold for 20 three times at that hour, I want to add it three times, so the average is correct
                    for i in range(int(quantity[day - index])):
                        item_date[f'{date[day]}'].append(prices[day])
                    index += 1
                else:
                    continue
            print(item_date)
```

item_date is a dictionary
item_date keys are unique dates(by days)
item_date values are supposed to be lists of prices for that day(so I can later calculate the average price for that day).
item is a dictionary from the request 
item_price_data is a huge list in this format:
[["May 06 2021 22: +0",27.02,"1"],["May 06 2021 23: +0",26.373,"1"]]
The float is the price, and the string next to it is the amount of sold items.
I want to take all the prices from 1 day and append them to a list, which is a value of the date key in my item_date dictionary.
The problem is, when I print the dictionary the values are all lists of one float, but there should be many floats in every list. 
If You have any questions I will gladly answer any of them, thank You for all the help in advance!

Comment: Each time you do `item_date[f'{date}'] = []` you're throwing away previous items on the same date. You should only do that if there isn't yet an element in the dictionary for that date.

Comment: You could use `item_date = defaultdict(list)` and then it will create the elements as needed automatically.

Comment: @Barmar You mean like that?

for current_day in item_price_data:
                date = datetime.strptime(current_day[0][0:11], "%b %d %Y")
                if item_date[f'{date}']:
                    continue
                else:
                    item_date[f'{date}'] = []

It returns:

KeyError: '2019-11-19 00:00:00'

Comment: @Barmar I used the defaultdict like You suggested, but the list values are still only 1-element, while I want it to append them

Comment: Did you get rid of the line that initializes the dictionary element?

Comment: Yes, I updated the code in the main post, You can check it out

Comment: `item_date[f'{date[day]}'] = [prices[day]]` should use `append()` to add to the list.

Comment: Thank You so so very much! That solved this problem